# PHP: Call to undefined method in Google Play Developer API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-play-developer-api

I'm going to get list of my in-app products from using google API, by its PHP client from a remote server.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher");

$service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);
$optParams = array('token' => 'my token....');
$results = $service->inappproducts->list ('my.package.name', $optParams);
```

When I run this code I get the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Inappproducts_Resource::list()`

I implemented my code based on some samples and details listed in [api reference](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/list). I just brought var_dump of `$service->inappproducts` for your reference:

```
object(Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_Inappproducts_Resource)#14 (7) { ["stackParameters":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> array(10) { ["alt"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["fields"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["trace"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["userIp"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["quotaUser"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["data"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(4) "body" } ["mimeType"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(6) "header" } ["uploadType"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["mediaUpload"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "complex" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } ["prettyPrint"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["location"]=> string(5) "query" } } ["rootUrl":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> string(27) "https://www.googleapis.com/" ["client":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> object(Google_Client)#1 (9) { ["auth":"Google_Client":private]=> NULL ["io":"Google_Client":private]=> NULL ["cache":"Google_Client":private]=> NULL ["config":"Google_Client":private]=> object(Google_Config)#2 (1) { ["configuration":protected]=> array(7) { ["application_name"]=> string(0) "" ["auth_class"]=> string(18) "Google_Auth_OAuth2" ["io_class"]=> string(14) "Google_IO_Curl" ["cache_class"]=> string(17) "Google_Cache_File" ["logger_class"]=> string(18) "Google_Logger_Null" ["base_path"]=> string(26) "https://www.googleapis.com" ["classes"]=> array(10) { ["Google_IO_Abstract"]=> array(1) { ["request_timeout_seconds"]=> int(100) } ["Google_IO_Curl"]=> array(2) { ["disable_proxy_workaround"]=> bool(false) ["options"]=> NULL } ["Google_Logger_Abstract"]=> array(4) { ["level"]=> string(5) "debug" ["log_format"]=> string(42) "[%datetime%] %level%: %message% %context% " ["date_format"]=> string(13) "d/M/Y:H:i:s O" ["allow_newlines"]=> bool(true) } ["Google_Logger_File"]=> array(3) { ["file"]=> string(12) "php://stdout" ["mode"]=> int(416) ["lock"]=> bool(false) } ["Google_Http_Request"]=> array(2) { ["disable_gzip"]=> bool(false) ["enable_gzip_for_uploads"]=> bool(false) } ["Google_Auth_OAuth2"]=> array(13) { ["client_id"]=> string(71) "" ["client_secret"]=> string(24) "" ["redirect_uri"]=> string(42) "https://android-e1test.rhcloud.com/verify/" ["developer_key"]=> string(0) "" ["hd"]=> string(0) "" ["prompt"]=> string(0) "" ["openid.realm"]=> string(0) "" ["include_granted_scopes"]=> string(0) "" ["login_hint"]=> string(0) "" ["request_visible_actions"]=> string(0) "" ["access_type"]=> string(6) "online" ["approval_prompt"]=> string(4) "auto" ["federated_signon_certs_url"]=> string(42) "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs" } ["Google_Task_Runner"]=> array(5) { ["initial_delay"]=> int(1) ["max_delay"]=> int(60) ["factor"]=> int(2) ["jitter"]=> float(0.5) ["retries"]=> int(0) } ["Google_Service_Exception"]=> array(1) { ["retry_map"]=> array(4) { [500]=> int(-1) [503]=> int(-1) ["rateLimitExceeded"]=> int(-1) ["userRateLimitExceeded"]=> int(-1) } } ["Google_IO_Exception"]=> array(1) { ["retry_map"]=> array(5) { [6]=> int(-1) [7]=> int(-1) [28]=> int(-1) [35]=> int(-1) [52]=> int(-1) } } ["Google_Cache_File"]=> array(1) { ["directory"]=> string(18) "/tmp/Google_Client" } } } } ["logger":"Google_Client":private]=> NULL ["deferExecution":"Google_Client":private]=> bool(false) ["requestedScopes":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(48) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher" } ["services":protected]=> array(0) { } ["authenticated":"Google_Client":private]=> bool(false) } ["serviceName":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> string(16) "androidpublisher" ["servicePath":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> string(33) "androidpublisher/v2/applications/" ["resourceName":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> string(13) "inappproducts" ["methods":"Google_Service_Resource":private]=> array(7) { ["batch"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(19) "inappproducts/batch" ["httpMethod"]=> string(4) "POST" ["parameters"]=> array(0) { } } ["delete"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(33) "{packageName}/inappproducts/{sku}" ["httpMethod"]=> string(6) "DELETE" ["parameters"]=> array(2) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["sku"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } } } ["get"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(33) "{packageName}/inappproducts/{sku}" ["httpMethod"]=> string(3) "GET" ["parameters"]=> array(2) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["sku"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } } } ["insert"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(27) "{packageName}/inappproducts" ["httpMethod"]=> string(4) "POST" ["parameters"]=> array(2) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["autoConvertMissingPrices"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(7) "boolean" } } } ["list"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(27) "{packageName}/inappproducts" ["httpMethod"]=> string(3) "GET" ["parameters"]=> array(4) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["maxResults"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(7) "integer" } ["startIndex"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(7) "integer" } ["token"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" } } } ["patch"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(33) "{packageName}/inappproducts/{sku}" ["httpMethod"]=> string(5) "PATCH" ["parameters"]=> array(3) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["sku"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["autoConvertMissingPrices"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(7) "boolean" } } } ["update"]=> array(3) { ["path"]=> string(33) "{packageName}/inappproducts/{sku}" ["httpMethod"]=> string(3) "PUT" ["parameters"]=> array(3) { ["packageName"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["sku"]=> array(3) { ["location"]=> string(4) "path" ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["required"]=> bool(true) } ["autoConvertMissingPrices"]=> array(2) { ["location"]=> string(5) "query" ["type"]=> string(7) "boolean" } } } } }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm in a similar boat.  Their stupid php client library has zero documentation, no info on any of the functions or classes, and which ones your supposed to use to do what.

Comment: Um dude, your client id and client secret are in that var dump.  Might want to change those now.

Comment: @CaptainHypertext thanks! I've checked var_dump before posting, but I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm shooting from the hip here, but try this:

```
$results = $service->inappproducts->listInappproducts('my.package.name', $optParams);
```

Instead of:

```
$results = $service->inappproducts->list ('my.package.name', $optParams);
```

And as I commented, you should change your client secret, since it looks like you posted in your var_dump there.

Comment: did you fixed it upon documentation of php client or according to var_dumps?

Comment: It leads to new exception: `Error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET .... Login Required' in google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110 `

Comment: I fixed it by looking around in the Google php library source code. I keep having to figure out if the method name is `list()` or `listLables()` or whatever (I'm working with the gmail api). But it looks like that fixed the problem. Now, based on the error message, it sounds like your request is failing because Google wants you to authenticate.  Maybe [this link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/8) will help?